# Node.JS Error: bash: cd: lambda: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cli, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to get this [Alexa audio player skill example](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/tree/mainline/single-stream) to work. I'm stuck at **3. You need to download NodeJS dependencies : $ (cd lambda && npm install)** with error `bash: cd: lambda: No such file or directory`

I installed the AWS SDK and AWS CLI. I'm using Node JS Version v10.6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.
How to create the *lambda* directory?

Comment: You need to clone the linked repo first, then cd into it then follow the instructions.

Comment: @lependu Thanks, that fixed it.